# Getting principal exception while performing such acions using <portlet:actionURL> in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

```
<portlet:actionURL var="meTooURL">
  <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/message_boards/edit_message" />
  <portlet:param name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" value="METOO" />
  <portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= currentURL %>" />
  <portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= PortalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL(request) %>" />
  <portlet:param name="messageId" value="<%= String.valueOf(message.getMessageId()) %>" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<liferay-ui:icon
  id="<%= String.valueOf(message.getMessageId()) %>"
  image="me-too"
  label="<%= false %>"
  message="Me Too"
  url="<%= meTooURL %>"           
/>
```

Here below is my logs :

```
12:18:04,274 WARN  [http-bio-8081-exec-39][PortletRequestProcessor:157] This URL can only be invoked using POST: /web/testdrive/message?p_auth=z9cdLBCVGIoF26tN9s7xHqtzgyzpZ1mY&p_p_id=19&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=2&_19_cmd=METOO&_19_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fjcdev.test.com%2Fweb%2Ftestdrive%2Fmessage%2F-%2Fmessage_boards%2Fmessage%2F94122&_19_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fjcdev.test.com%2Fweb%2Fthread%2Fposts-notifications%2F94122&_19_struts_action=%2Fmessage_boards%2Fedit_message&_19_messageId=94122
12:18:04,322 ERROR [http-bio-8081-exec-39][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException: /web/testdrive/message?p_auth=z9cdLBCVGIoF26tN9s7xHqtzgyzpZ1mY&p_p_id=19&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=2&_19_cmd=METOO&_19_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fjcdev.test.com%2Fweb%2Ftestdrive%2Fmessage%2F-%2Fmessage_boards%2Fmessage%2F94122&_19_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fjcdev.test.com%2Fweb%2Fthread%2Fposts-notifications%2F94122&_19_struts_action=%2Fmessage_boards%2Fedit_message&_19_messageId=94122
```

Comment: ` This URL can only be invoked using POST` this says you should be using POST action method and Principal Exceptions states that you are not having proper authentication while performing this action.

Comment: Pankaj, I already give permission to power user so that he/she can perform this action but than also it's not working.

Comment: Where do you have this code placed? In a portlet, hook?

Comment: this code is in jsp hook.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pankajkumar Kathiriya wisely pointed out, the problem is not the permissions, is that you are making a GET request when the action requires an POST request to process the action method. I would try to define the method of the icon to POST:

```
<liferay-ui:icon
  id="<%= String.valueOf(message.getMessageId()) %>"
  image="me-too"
  label="<%= false %>"
  message="Me Too"
  url="<%= meTooURL %>"           
  method="post"
/>
```

If that fails — sorry, I cannot test it now :( — you can write a JavaScript function to submit the request via POST and the give it to the `onClick` argument from the `<liferay-ui:icon>` tag.

Comment: I tried your code and also tried submit the request via POST but it's not working.

Comment: When it fails again, does it show the same error message or another error message?

Comment: Yes it shows the same error message.And I also tried with submitting form using '<form><input type="submit" ></input></form>'. But it shows the same error message.